# Check availability between two dates in a day field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Helo,
I am trying to get the products available between two dates through calendar table where I have relation with the product.

I put the data of my table:

[image]

[image]

I understand that if I do a foreach and I'm checking day by day I can get it, but I do not want it that way, I want to do it correctly with mysql

This is the query that I am currently executing and does not give me the expected results. this is [name the my page](http://www.nombrespara.net/)

```
    $start_date  = fecha_mysql_slash($this->input->get('start_date'));
    $end_date    = fecha_mysql_slash($this->input->get('end_date'));
    $calendars   = new Calendar();
    $calendars->select("*")
    ->where('day BETWEEN "'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$newEndDate.'" and availability > 0')
    ->include_related("producto",NULL,TRUE,TRUE)
    ->group_by("producto_id")
    ->get()->all;
```

Now I will try to explain to me, through a form I get the start date and also the end date, so I have to check in the calendar table from start date to end date if exists in the field "day" and also Which has availability greater than 0., well with this query I can not get it.

Currently there is no error, the problem is that I get products, when on the dates that I indicate does not exist in the table and field "day"

For example I make the query through the dates 2017-03-13 and 2017-03-25, the problem that I think I do not understand because I get the product id, when from 2017-03-13 there are no records for these product.

I hope you can help me,

thank you very much.

Comment: whats is the error ? Try with this. BETWEEN ("'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$newEndDate.'" ) and

Comment: I just tried it and with the parentheses it does not work for me. Currently there is no error, the problem is that I get products, when on the dates that I indicate does not exist in the table and field "day"

Comment: SELECT * from products WHERE (products.day BETWEEN '2017-03-12' AND '2017-03-16') <<-- this is a simple sql query which gets the result. you can convert it into active records add availability check and get the result

Comment: I just simulated the case http://prntscr.com/ej9oh3 have a look

Comment: For example I make the query through the dates 2017-03-13 and 2017-03-25, the problem that I think I do not understand because I get the product id, when from 2017-03-16 there are no records for these product.

Comment: change to ->where("day BETWEEN "'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$newEndDate.'" and availability > 0")

Comment: no. it is " 'double quotes' not single   where("day .... 0")

Comment: thanks, but no work

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
$end_date    = fecha_mysql_slash($this->input->get('end_date'));
```

and

```
->where('day BETWEEN "'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$newEndDate.'" and availability > 0')
```

$end_date is a different variable from $newEndDate. Change $newEndDate to $end_date and it should work.